# Shortcut Keys in eclipse Ganymede version

Tags: eclipse

I want to know program shortcut keys in eclipse Ganymede  version like...
System.out.println();
public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: This should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of all available templates and names  by following below configuration window :

```
window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> templates
```